# Store XML retrieved value as string variable for use in child package

Tags: sql-server, xml, variables, ssis, etl

I would like to store an XML retrieved value as a string variable for later use in a child package within SSIS. The situation is as follows:

I'm retrieving an ID from an XML file in a data flow task (A). I need to save this ID as a variable so I can pass it later on to a child package via package configurations and use it there. The issue is that with the 'Recordset Destination', I can only store it as an object type, and then I can't seem to convert it in my child package to a string again.

I think that I can solve this with a foreach loop, but I don't feel like this is very performant. Is there any other way to do this? I attached some screenshots to make the situation a bit more clear.

Thanks!

**Screenshots**

[image: Dataflow A]

[image]

Comment: It also sounds like you might not need a dataflow task all. You could simply have an execute SQL task in the control flow that writes to a variable.

Comment: @KeithL, I suppose that this is possible, but I can't read from the XML in the control flow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Script Component to Store the ID value in a variable, Just add the script component as destination, select the variable as `Read\Write` variable in the script form. And assign a value to this variable in the `PostExecute()` function inside the Script Editor.

You can refer to one of the following link for more information:

- [How to use variables in a Script Component](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html)
- [Using Variables in the Script Component](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337079(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Read and Write variables in a Script Component in SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) using C#](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/read-and-write-variables-in-a-script-component-in-ssis-sql-server-integration-services-using-c/)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much for this. I didn't know that I could use the script component as a destination!